Can you change the default font used in synaptic package manager GUI?
I was adding some fonts to my system and discovered at somepoint an update [I hope?] or something installed well over a thousand versions [primarily various languages not being used] of Noto fonts. I checked my system pref [through gui] and made sure none of the Noto fonts were in use and then used synaptic to remove 3 of installed Noto packages. I left one as it was titled 'Noto something UI'.
L-s: Apprently one of the fonts in the packages removed was being used by synaptic itself & I dont speak 000 nor am i familiar enough with the program to know where the "history" function is. Further I dont remember the three file names exactly. Is there any other way to either "undo" what I did simply? or another way through terminal, etc to change the font used in synaptic [& perhaps anything else I find unreadable later?]
Lastly, I haven't closed the program or done anyting since i hit "apply" to remove the packages, which may or may not matter. If not obv too, I am new to linux and am at-best a moderate beginner with commandline interfaces. Deatils maybe of some use below.
Linux-lite 7.0-Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
synaptic/noble,now 0.91.3build4 amd64 [installed]

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

If it were Ubuntu, you could check the logs at /var/log/apt to see what packages you removed, and reinstall them using the command line. No clue about linux lite though.

@guiverc will do;

@Organic Marble, That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Just FYI the file was under the same path for me. In general most paths are consistent on this os I've noticed.

Synaptic v0.91.3 (and v0.91.2 on Ubuntu 22.04).
Go to Settings > Columns and Fonts > Fonts check Use custom application font and click in the Applications Font box to select the font you require. The default will likely be Sans Regularsize 10.


Unfortunatly doing this wasn't possible until after figuring out which packages were missing and reinstalling [As every bit of text in the program just showed 000] Which I found under Organic Marble's suggestion /var/log/apt ; However, I was able to to use your suggestion to change the program font after, allowing me to delete the excess packages, again.; A simple system restart also worked though i'm not sure how. My guess is the program automatically chose a new default on its own. Regardless. thank you for the response!

The though occurred to me when posting the answer that, as the font selected was fixed in the app, it was not possible to delete it in case it caused problems elsewhere but by selecting and fixing a different font in synaptic, the system then allowed its removal. Thanks for the feedback and for accepting the answer. Much appreciated.
